# Transaction to load data infile and then update columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to load new rows into a table and then update other columns in the table with the uploaded IDs. I'm only uploading IDs and then joining other tables to pull other data into the table. Query I tried:

```
START TRANSACTION
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'file path' REPLACE INTO 
    TABLE
        tablex CHARACTER SET
        latin1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (`date_orderable`,
        `id1`,
        `id2,
        `id3,
        `d1`,
        `d2,
        `d3,
        );
update tablex a left join uber_data b on a.id1 = b.id1 
set a.d1 =b.d1;
update tablex a left join uber_data b on a.id2 = b.id2 
set a.d2 =b.d2;
update tablex a left join uber_data b on a.id2 = b.id1 
set a.d3 =b.d3;
COMMIT
```

It says there's an error in line 2 when running. Anyone know how I can load data into the table and then update the new rows? Thanks!

Comment: Which error are you getting ?

Comment: just says error in syntax starting with the load data infile line

Comment: You are missing a semicolon at the end of `START TRANSACTION` : should be `START TRANSACTION;`

Comment: Also there are missing backticks in some of the fields in the list.

Comment: i had one but when i run the query, it only runs that first line

Comment: the back ticks are there in the real query. I forgot them in this example

Comment: How do you run the script ? From mysql workbench ? php ?

Comment: running the query from Dbeaver 5.3.3

Comment: I think you do need the `;` on `START TRANSACTION;` ; otherwise, that is a syntax error. Then, you would need to understand why your client is not running all statements in your script. I don't know Dbeaver so I cannot really advise how to, but I think that's what you need to look into.

Comment: PS : please update your question to add the missing backticks, to avoid other readers to believe that this is the cause of the syntax error.

Comment: Thanks! You're right that I just needed the semi colon. I tried the query in HeidiSQL and it worked. Not sure why Dbeaver was not running the whole query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several syntax errors in your query :

- there are unbalanced backticks around some of the fields in the list (like `` d2,</code> should be <code>d2`, ``
- a semicolon is missing at the end of the `START TRANSACTION;` statement, and at the end of the `COMMIT;` statement as well. Without the semicolon, MySQL tries to parse two statements at once, which generates a syntax error